# Timer object returning argument Nº error

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, compiler-errors

Was working on a simple timer function, but hit a wall. Code in question is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import threading
Timer = threading.Timer()
def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Code is a direct copy of the one in https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects
Since the function `hello` takes no args I don't understand the error output of:

```
  File "timer_test.py", line 3, in <module>
Timer = threading.Timer()
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1047, in Timer
return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Does the `Timer` require another argument other then the time itself and the function to be executed? Shouldn't the args/kwargs not need to be passed since the function `hello` takes none? I tried passing arbitrary arguments such as `None` or `[]` but it changed nothing.

I know it's probably a stupid problem, but since the documentation doesn't answer me, and I couldn't find an answer already on here I decided to post this.
Thank you for your time/help

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct copy. It has an extra line:

```
Timer = threading.Timer()
```

In this line, you try to create a time, but do not pass the delay and function arguments.

More on that, if that would work, you override the class name `Timer` with an object of the timer, and try to create another timer, but from an instance, not from the class. That will never work.

Remove that line, and make it exactly as in the docs.